# What is the difference between <NN>* and <NN.*>* in NLTK regex pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I went through [chapter 7](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch07.html) of the NLTK book looking for a solution to this but so far it unclear to me.

1. `<NN>*` means 0 or more of Nouns
2. `<NN.*>*` as explained by the book means **0 or more nouns of any type**

In NLTK are `NN`, `NNS`, `NNP`, `NNPS` exclusive of each other ? (I might be wrong in thinking that NN is an umbrella for the rest)

In that case does `<NN.*>*` mean that 0 or more of any of `NN`, `NNS`, `NNP`, `NNPS` which itself can be repeated 0 or more times(that outer *)?  Or does it simply mean `NN` repeated 0 or more times which again repeats 0 or more times?
Or am I completely mistaken ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html)'s a list of the Penn treebank POS tags. As you'll see, `NN` does not encompass `NNS`, `NNP`, and `NNPS`; it only represents singular and mass nouns.

> NN - Noun, singular or mass
>   NNS - Noun, plural
>   NNP - Proper noun, singular
>   NNPS - Proper noun, plural

`<NN.*>*` means any of `NN`, `NNS`, `NNP`, `NNPS` repeated 0 or more times (from the outer `*`), whereas `<NN>*` would mean only `<NN>` repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: Okay, so the internal `NN.*` in `<NN.*>*` just means **one** NN or NNS or NNP or NNPS, **not many** and then the outer * has the usual meaning. Is that correct? I mean the internal `*`, it is just a representative, it doesn't actually mean that something repeats 0 or more times (unlike the outer `*`). Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. The inner `*` is for repetitions of the `.`. Thus, that `.*` could match nothing, `S`, `P`, or `PS`, resulting in `NN`, `NNS`, `NNP`, and `NNPS` tags respectively. The outer `*` is responsible for repetitions of the entire tag.